# Consulta sobre uso de try catch en java. Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, poo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    int edad;

    boolean repetir = true;

    while (repetir) {
        System.out.println("introduce edad");

        try {
            edad = entrada.nextInt();
            repetir = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            entrada.nextLine();//Si quito esta linea entra en un bucle infinito.. Por qué? No entiendo porque se pone este codigo
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Porque se pone este código en el catch.? entrada.nextLine();

Porque entra en un bucle infinito si lo quito?

Comment: Hola, es simple, al comenzar el bucle la variable `repetir` tendrá valor `true`, luego si en el `try`ocurre una excepción en la linea `edad = entrada.nextInt();` entonces la linea `repetir = false;` nunca se ejecutara por lo que la variable `repetir` nunca tendrá un valor `false` y entrará en un bucle infinito.

Comment: sigo sin entender bro, esta parte entrada.nextLine();

Comment: La exepción `InputMismatchException` es lanzada por la clase Scanner cuando el elemento recibido no corresponde al tipo de dato esperado (en este caso un no entero), por lo que la linea `entrada.nextLine();` recibe una linea sea de cualquier tipo eliminando el error. (Perdona se me acabo el espacio para comentar)

Comment: Mmmm, okay gracias bro, por la respuesta. Aunque no entendí del todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquella línea permite que el usuario ingresé al programa de nuevo una línea de texto. La excepción `InputMismatchException` es lanzada cuando el `scanner` recibe un valor de entrada que no espera.

Sin esta parte el programa entraría en un bucle infinito porque el la condición para que se repita el bucle `while` siempre es `true`. Dicho de otra manera, porque la variable `repetir` es inicializada con `true` y jamás haces que cambie de valor, por lo tanto se seguirá repitiendo el bucle `while`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    int edad;

    boolean repetir = true;

    while (repetir) {
        System.out.println("introduce edad");

        try {
            edad = entrada.nextInt();
            repetir = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            repetir = false();
            // Ya puedes eliminar la línea que iba aquí.
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Si haces esto podrás darle final al bucle cuando encuentre un error y haya entrado en el bloque `catch`. Con el anterior código podrás borrar la línea que obliga a la entrada del teclado por parte del usuario.

Comment: Ahhh ya entendi, gracias Bro. Con ese ejemplo si lo entendi, pero con el entrada.nextLine();   no puedo entenderlo, no le encuentro el sentido.